# JTextFields don't show up, but they're still there. (the first one is "bugily" visible)

Tags: java, swing, jframe, visibility, jtextfield

It worked an hour ago, but I must have done something to the code and I have no idea what. My `JTextField`s don't show up, but if I set them to editable, they're still there. The first `JTextField` does show up, but looks weird. Any ideas what's wrong? (I call my `JTextField`s "Square"). Size = 10

```
package gui;

import javax.swing.*;
import engine.GameEngine;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MineFieldGUI extends JFrame {
    private GameEngine engine;
    Square[][] field;
    int size = 10;

    public MineFieldGUI(GameEngine minefield) {     
        super("MineField");
        this.engine = minefield;
        this.size = minefield.getSize();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.setSize(300, 350);
        Locale.setDefault(new Locale("en"));

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menubar);
        JMenu helpMenu = new JMenu("Help");
        menubar.add(helpMenu);
        helpMenu.add(new HelpMenu(this));



        //***THE MINE-FIELD***
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(size,size));
        field = new Square[size][size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                field[i][j] = new Square(i, j);
                panel.add(field[i][j]);
            }
        }
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);    
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void setColor(int x, int y){
        field[x][y].setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    }

    public void setText(int x, int y, String text){
        field[x][y].setText(text);
    }

    public String getText(int x, int y){
        return field[x][y].getText();
    }
}
```

My textFields:

```
package gui;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Square extends JTextField {

    int posX;
    int posY;

    public Square(int x, int y) {
        super("");
        posX = x;
        posY = y;

        this.setEditable(false);
        this.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    }

    public int getX(){
        return posX;
    }
    public int getY(){
        return posY;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the methods `getX` and `getY` which are being used by the layout manager to position the `Square`  components. This will let the layout manager correctly position the buttons.

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick! But why? How did those methods cause a problem?

Comment: You were _overriding_ those methods - the layout manager then using them to position the components...

Comment: You sure? I just added them myself. Didn't know I overrode anything

Comment: Yep, just try adding the `@Override` annotation. See the docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getX()) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getY())